# Rust MongoDB findOne not working with $or

Tags: mongodb, rust

I'm trying to query a MongoDB collection using an `$or` query, but for some reason it is not working.

Here is the document I'm trying to query, which is the only document in its collection:

```
{"_id":{"$oid":"64be8e2689e1214e4930d36b"},"initiator":{"$oid":"64b42c63e302b112bc7c8dbc"},"target":{"$oid":"64ba9f4bef8b64c5b92ecb40"},"status":"InitiatorRequested","timestamp":{"$date":{"$numberLong":"1690209830575"}},"accept_timestamp":null}
```

Here is my original code, `user` and `target` are both of type `bson::oid::ObjectId` (`user` is the initiator and `target` is the target, both are indexed):

```rust
db.auto_collection::<Friend>().find_one(doc! {
    "$or": [
        {
            "initiator": user,
            "target": target,
        },
        {
            "initiator": target,
            "target": user,
        }
    ],
}, None).await?
```

This does not return the document, but the code below does:

```rust
db.auto_collection::<Friend>().find_one(doc! {
    "$or": [
        {
            "initiator": user,
            "target": target,
        },
    ],
}, None).await?
```

Why could this be happening? The second operator shouldn't even apply, yet it kills the entire operation. No error is returned from either query.

Comment: I have never used that library, but could be related to rust ownership?  If `user` and `target` are not references or copy, try to clone them in the first `or` item.

Comment: @StevenSpungin If there would be an owenrship problem, the code wouldn't compile.

Comment: Just to be sure... When you say "_does not return the document_" you mean that it returns _no_ documents, correct? As opposed to returning a different document?

Comment: @user20042973 Correct. The first query returns no documents. There is only that one document in the collection, anyways.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem turned out to be that the fields were indexed. I'm not sure if this is a bug or intended behavior, but removing both indices solved the issue. This was for MongoDB version 6.3.2.